# Numpy Matrix Multiplication Explanation

Tags: python, numpy

I am working through some math exercises and I do not understand why my numpy matrix multiplication is not working.

So I have:

```
t = np.array([[6,-1],[2,3]])
c = np.array([[1,1], [1,2]])
cinv = np.linalg.inv(c)
```

Which gives me:

```
t:
   [[ 6 -1]
    [ 2  3]]
c:
   [[1 1]
    [1 2]]
cinv:
   [[ 2. -1.]
    [-1.  1.]]
```

Now when I run my equation I get the following:

```
cinv*t*c
array([[12.,  1.],
       [-2.,  6.]])
```

Which this is not correct. I did it over a couple times and the correct answer is (5,0)(0,4). Why is the multiplication being carried out by position instead of row * column?

Can someone help me out with what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Using `*` does elementwise multiplication, not dot product. Use `@` for a dot product multiplication. This is Numpy's choice for overloading operators. In fact, in the original Python design however, `@` was designated for matrix multiplication, which is probably why this is the case.

```py
import numpy as np


t = np.array([[6,-1],[2,3]])
c = np.array([[1,1], [1,2]])
cinv = np.linalg.inv(c)

print(cinv@t@c)
"""
Result:
[[5. 0.]
 [0. 4.]]
"""
```

Often times, I find it a lot easier to read to use strict functions and not the overloaded operators (though they can get crowded fast).

`np.dot(A, B)` or `A.dot(B)` work as dot products

Here's some [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) on what each symbol does, explicitly.

Comment: Actually the `@` operator, `np.matmul` is a recent addition to python.  It works like `dot`, but with different handling of 3d ('batched') arrays.  The use of `*` for elementwise operation is consistent with the use of `+` and `-` (and other binary operators).  An older array language `APL` uses `+.×` as the matrix multiplication, with clear allusion to its `sum-of-products` nature.